# A proposal's definition/description

Tags: discussion, area-51

The other day I noticed that [the Arabic Language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language)'s description/definition was edited, [here is the discussion I made](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18567/is-there-a-reason-why-the-proposal-definition-was-edited?noredirect=1#comment27649_18567) which still hasn't received an answer, then it was brought up in a [comment](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18567/is-there-a-reason-why-the-proposal-definition-was-edited?noredirect=1#comment27649_18567) that the edit could have been a mistake, and that the editor did not realize it was arabic text.  Although I am not totally sure this is the reason, but this has made me wonder,

Is there some list of rules or something in regards to editing proposal definitions/descriptions?

Comment: I believe it's quite commonplace to remove other languages from the description after a while. All the "*x* Language" sites have, at some point, had the non-English components removed from their descriptions. I'm not completely sure why, but I can assure you they *did* know it was Arabic text.